# Wordpress: Implement basic HTML form functionality to retrieve data and visualize the results

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have experience in HMTL/PHP but I cannot understand how someone could implement this basic functionality in Wordpress. I could not find an article or web page on their website or by searching through the internet.

I want to create a basic html form, pass some data as select queries in a database and visualize back the results paginated.

In traditional PHP we are using "action" in order to send the form data through POST or GET to the action page and then with some PHP code we can fetch the data and visualize it with tables etc.

I cannot understand how to do such a thing in a wordpress page. Where the action parameter should point to? How could I implement this basic functionality in WordPress?

Please could someone help?

Comment: The form action should point to your processing script (where ever that may be). It's exactly the same in 'traditional PHP'.

Comment: Ok, in this case I have an empty page, without header, footer etc related to the active theme. That is why I am asking related to WordPress

Comment: Also it does not reply to the question on how am I supposed to access the page containing the processing PHP script from the WordPress panel. Ok I could enter action=processing.php , but how am I supposed to access this processing.php from the WordPress admin panel?

Comment: you should check my answer this will give your solution. try that and if u have any doubts you should comment it.

Comment: Are you solved this probelm ??

Answer (score 2):

This is the mode to develop a separated .php file which uses your wordpress theme and can access to almost all wordpress functions:

```
<?php include(’wp-blog-header.php’); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<!– Your code here –>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then you can use all WordPress functions cited here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference
You can save this file anywhere, but be sure to insert correct path to wp-blog-header and there must not be any prohibiting .htaccess

This is the way to insert php code into a wordpress post:
You have to use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/ 
Then create a post and use `[php] [/php]` to insert your php code and open it. Look at the address bar. This it the URL to access this post. Use it as action parameter in your form. Then control $_REQUEST[] in your php code to extract parameters received from your form.
Now you can control this post as any other normal wordpress post from the wordpress admin panel.

Comment: Any references to WordPress web page? I could not find anything there.

Comment: wp-blog-header permit you use all wordpress functions in external .php files

Comment: Sorry but I need to know how to access the action page from the wordpress admin panel. I mean what will be the name in the action parameter and at the same time how can I access that page in order to write the PHP script?

Comment: sorry made negative and i cannot change it now, please modify and i will change it.. The point is that still it is not clear..

Comment: @maiky answer updated(the second method). Now it is more clear?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom wordpress templates for pages in your theme. Here i use templates
1.form-page.php  --- with template name **"Form-page-template"** and
2.form-page-action.php  ---with template name **"Form-page-action-template"**

form-page.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Form-page-template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<form method="post" action="http://yourdomain.com/form-page-action/" name="input-form"/>

<!-- form contents -->

</form>   

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You just save this template inside your theme : location => like wp-contents/themes/your-theme/form-page.php . and this will add **Form-page-template** in your theme .Now create a page inside from wordpress dashboard through pages->addnew ,here i give page name "**form-page**" and select template for page from right pannel,here we need to select "**Form-page-template**" that we created early.

Now we have the page url :: http://yourdomain.com/form-page/ where we can see our form,now create form-action-page.

2.form-page-action.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Form-page-action-template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- Your action page contents goes here -->
<?php
//getting input etc.. you need to do
$input = $post['input'];

?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now you need to save this template inside your theme as above, Create a new page for this template as said above here i creating a page "**form-page-action**" with template "**Form-page-action-template**" so here i get a page url for our 
action page like :: http://yourdomain.com/form-page-action/ , and you need to use this url as the action url in your form page.and this way you can add your form action page inside wordpress theme.

You can edit the contents of these page inside from wordpress like=>  Appreance -> Editor , select the templates to edit.

Comment: sorry but I do not understand. I have done all the things that you write, but I cannot see how can I add form content in 1.form-page.php , as I cannot find this page in WordPress admin panel in order to edit it and potentially add it in the menu..

Comment: Also in the action page, I am editing it in the wordpress panel but the changes are not reflected when I view the page...

Comment: You can edit the contents of these page inside from wordpress dashboard from Appreance -> Editor , select the templates form-page-template and form-page-action-template to edit.

To add menu to pages use use pages inside wordpress pages , form-page or form-action-page.

Comment: The most important thing in all these is after adding template inside theme. when you are adding page from dashboard pages->add new , you need to change the template of page from default template to template that we created.here form-page page eith form-page-template and form-action-page with form-action=page-template

Comment: please comment what is your actual problem when you tried to do this